How to use jinja2/html to convert a numpy.arr int to htlm
I may be a bit confusing on how to handle a numpy.arr int table to html/jinja2
In my python app I set the variable to contingency table
the table is original
contingency_table=np.zeros((6,6), dtype=int)
it does not display anything
I would like it to look like

I have played with code trying to get the table to look like this with out avil. Any help is much appreciate.
<h1>Contingency Table</h1>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped mx-auto">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>XXXXXXXX</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>XXXXXXXX(1)</td>
        {% for item_table in contingency_table %}
        <td>{{ item_table[0][0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[0][1] }}</td>            
        <td>{{ item_table[0][2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[0][3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[0][4] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[0][5] }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>XXXXXXXX(2)</td>
        {% for item_table in contingency_table %}
        <td>{{ item_table[1][0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[1][1] }}</td>            
        <td>{{ item_table[1][2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[1][3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[1][4] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[1][5] }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>XXXXXXXX (3)</td>
        {% for item_table in contingency_table %}
        <td>{{ item_table[2][0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[2][1] }}</td>            
        <td>{{ item_table[2][2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[2][3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[2][4] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[2][5] }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>XXXXXXXX(4)</td>
        {% for item_table in contingency_table %}
        <td>{{ item_table[3][0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[3][1] }}</td>            
        <td>{{ item_table[3][2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[3][3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[3][4] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[3][5] }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>XXXXXXXX (5)</td>
        {% for item_table in contingency_table %}
        <td>{{ item_table[4][0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[4][1] }}</td>            
        <td>{{ item_table[4][2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[4][3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[4][4] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[4][5] }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>XXXXXXXX (6)</td>
        {% for item_table in contingency_table %}
        <td>{{ item_table[5][0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[5][1] }}</td>            
        <td>{{ item_table[5][2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[5][3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[5][4] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_table[5][5] }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


I needed to put it in a list from a numpy.ndarray
